# Should I do the reverse-normalisation after pass the last activation function

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, normalization, activation-function

I have been working on frame interpolation on Pytorch, and I have one question to ask about image normalization.
Before train a model, I normalized the image dataset, with `mean=[0.3852, 0.3699, 0.3618]` and `std=[0.2444, 0.2472, 0.2391]` (this is the mean and std of my whole dataset)
When training model, I passed feature maps through a sigmoid function. Now, I want to visualize the last output. Should I do the reverse-normalization before visualization? The same question when the last activation is tanh function.